# Creating function with variable number of arguments or parameters in Dart

Tags: dart

I am looking for a way to create a function with a variable number of arguments or parameters in Dart. I know I could create an array parameter instead, but I would prefer to not do that because I'm working on a library where syntactic brevity is important.

For example, in plain JavaScript, we could do something like this (borrowed from [here](http://terrainformatica.com/sciter/js-dart-tis.htm)):

```js
function superHeroes() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log("There's no stopping " + arguments[i]);
  }
}

superHeroes('UberMan', 'Exceptional Woman', 'The Hunk');
```

However, in dart, that code will not run. Is there a way to do the same thing in dart? If not, is this something that is on the roadmap?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1014 (I would not hold my breath, it's open for 7.5 years)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't do that for now.

I don't really know if *varargs* will come back - they were there some times ago but [have been removed](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/0cQZpHs5D-g/NrKOuizLnqEJ).

However it is possible to emulate *varargs* with [Emulating functions](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/emulating-functions/). See the below code snippet.

```dart
typedef OnCall = dynamic Function(List arguments);

class VarargsFunction {
  VarargsFunction(this._onCall);
  
  final OnCall _onCall;

  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    if (!invocation.isMethod || invocation.namedArguments.isNotEmpty)
      super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
    final arguments = invocation.positionalArguments;
    return _onCall(arguments);
  }
}

main() {
  final superHeroes = VarargsFunction((arguments) {
    for (final superHero in arguments) {
      print("There's no stopping ${superHero}");
    }
  }) as dynamic;
  superHeroes('UberMan', 'Exceptional Woman', 'The Hunk');
}
```

Comment: Wow thats a really neat solution. I do like the way dart handles arguments, but this would help with developers who like it the other way.

Comment: Very nice! I had not looked much into the InvocationMirror part of the language, so thanks for a great example. I tweaked your answer slightly to create a version that works on the current version of Dart.

Comment: I copy and paste above code, However I got `Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 3 found.
Try removing the extra arguments.dart(extra_positional_arguments)` error during the `superHeroes('UberMan', 'Exceptional Woman', 'The Hunk');` line. I have to change `final superHeroes = VarargsFunction((arguments)` to `final dynamic superHeroes = VarargsFunction((arguments)` for fixing.

Comment: Dart is not a Javascript!
Please don't use syntax like "final x = MyFunction( () {...});, it's not an idiomatic Dart, and don't use `dynamic` unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @SergeyMolchanovsky Why wouldn't it be idiomatic? `VarargsFunction` is a class that takes a function as a constructor parameter, and the function in this case is an anonymous function. It's just as idiomatic as calling `list.map((x) {...});`. And while this solution would certainly be classified as a hack, it requires the object to be typed as `dynamic` in order to work so this is a valid use of it.

Answer (score 13):

Dart does indirectly support var-args as long as you aren't too much into syntactic brevity.

```
void testFunction([List<dynamic> args=[]])
{
  for(dynamic arg:args)
  {
    // Handle each arg...
  }
}

testFunction([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
testFunction();
testFunction([0, 1, 2]);
```

**Note:** You can do the same thing with named parameters, but you'll have to handle things internally, just in case if the user (of that function; which could be you) decides to not pass any value to that named parameter.

---

I would like to thank @Ladicek for indirectly letting me know that a word like  **brevity** exists in English.

Comment: This is what I personally come up with before I open this page. After seeing all the answers here, I choose to keep using this solution because the other solution looks like a hack. I don't like how each function is defined. And yes, I'm not too much into syntactic brevity.

Answer (score 8):

This version:

1. Works with both positional and keyword arguments.
2. Supports typing of the return value.
3. Works with modern Dart.

```dart
typedef VarArgsCallback = void Function(List<dynamic> args, Map<String, dynamic> kwargs);

class VarArgsFunction {
  final VarArgsCallback callback;
  static var _offset = 'Symbol("'.length;

  VarArgsFunction(this.callback);

  void call() => callback([], {});

  @override
  dynamic noSuchMethod(Invocation inv) {
    return callback(
      inv.positionalArguments,
      inv.namedArguments.map(
        (_k, v) {
          var k = _k.toString();
          return MapEntry(k.substring(_offset, k.length - 2), v);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
    dynamic myFunc = VarArgsFunction((args, kwargs) {
      print('Got args: $args, kwargs: $kwargs');
    });
    myFunc(1, 2, x: true, y: false); // Got args: [1, 2], kwargs: {x: true, y: false}
}
```

Thanks, Alexandre for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13732459/7061265)!

Answer (score 7):

I played around a little with Alexandre Ardhuin's answer and found that we can tweak a couple of things to make this work in the current version of Dart:

```dart
class VarArgsClass {
  noSuchMethod(InvocationMirror invocation) {
    if (invocation.memberName == 'superheroes') {
      this.superheroes(invocation.positionalArguments);
    }
  }

  void superheroes(List<String> heroNames) {
    for (final superHero in heroNames) {
      print("There's no stopping ${superHero}!");
    }
  }
}

main() {
  new VarArgsClass().superheroes('UberMan', 'Exceptional Woman', 'The Hunk');
}
```

This has lots of problems, including:

- A warning is generated wherever you call `superheroes()` because the signature doesn't match your parameters.
- More manual checking would need to be done to make sure the list of arguments passed to superheroes is really a `List<String>`.
- Needing to check the member name in `noSuchMethod()` makes it more likely you'll forget to change the 'superheroes' string if you change the method name.
- Reflection makes the code path harder to trace.

BUT if you are fine with all of those issues, then this gets the job done.

Comment: There is one other issue that I believe _has to_ be mentioned: it will only work if you pass more than one argument. If you pass only one string, you will call the original superheroes method and the noSuchMethod machinery will be ignored.

Comment: This method will no longer work in modern versions of Dart for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 6):

If you are really into syntactic brevity, just declare a function/method with say 10 optional positional parameters and be done. It's unlikely someone will call that with more than 10 arguments.

If it sounds like a hack, that's because it *is* a hack. But I've seen the Dart team doing the same :-)

*For example*:

```dart
void someMethod(arg0, [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9]) {
  final args = [arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9];

  args.removeWhere((value) => value == null);

  /* do something the the args List */
  print(args);
}
```

Comment: And then the method must make special checks for each of the ten arguments (if arg1 != null ..., if arg2 != null ...)?  Gross!

Comment: I already said that it's a hack, and it has a price that the API designer might be willing to pay.

Comment: It's not scalable.

Comment: No it's not. I admitted it right in the answer. That said, after all those years, I still think it's by far the best answer of all provided here -- with the exception of simply using a list, of course.

Comment: That's how they did it in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-17?view=net-5.0

Comment: Can you show an example of how to call this method?

Comment: @RaSha You can code-generate the function if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

For the example you've written, I think you're best off using a list. Sorry about that!

I'm looking at dartbug.com, but I don't see a feature request for this. You're definitely welcome to create one!