# What is the equivalent of AS3's foo:* in Dart?

Tags: actionscript-3, dart

I just started using Dart, and I haven't been able to find answers to these issues.

How do these three AS3 lines translate into Dart?

1) `static var asset:*;`
<<-- basically how do I handle `*` type

2) `static function getAsset():* {`
<<-- same issue, how do I handle `*` type?

3) `static function loadImages(... images):void {`
<< -- how do I handle `...` argument?

Comment: These are three different questions. You might consider asking each one individually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ActionScript, but some quick Googling suggests that the asterisk means "can be any type".  Since Dart is optionally typed, this means you can just leave the type off.  I believe `static` works about the same in both languages.

So:

1) `static var asset:*;` becomes `static var asset;`

2) `static function getAsset():* {` becomes `static getAsset() {`

3) Dart doesn't support varargs, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13732459/1427098) has a workaround.