# Dart how to make a function that can accept any number of args

Tags: dart

Coming from `python`, i know i can easily accomplish that :

```
def someFunc(*args):
    for i in args:
        print i
```

That way i can give 100 args with ease.

How to do something like that on Dart ?

Thx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating function with variable number of arguments or parameters in Dart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731631/creating-function-with-variable-number-of-arguments-or-parameters-in-dart)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no real vararg support in Dart. There was, but it has been [removed](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/misc/0cQZpHs5D-g/NrKOuizLnqEJ). As Fox32 said, you can do this with `noSuchMethod`. But, if there is no real need to call the method like `method(param1, param2, param3)`, you could just skip this step and define a `Map` or `List` as parameter. Dart supports literals for both types, so the syntax is also short and clear:

```dart
void method1(List params) {
  params.forEach((value) => print(value));
}

void method2(Map params) {
  params.forEach((key, value) => print("$key -- $value"));
}

void main() {
  method1(["hello", "world", 123]);
  method2({"name":"John","someNumber":4711});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `noSuchMethod` method on a class (Probably in combination with the `call()` method, but i haven't tried that). But it seems like you loose some checking features of the dart editor when using this (at least for me).

The method has a [`Invocation`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_core/Invocation.html) instance as a parameter that contains the method name and all unnamed parameters as a list and all named parameters as a hashmap.

See [here](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/emulating-functions/) for more details about `noSuchMethod` and `call()`. But the link contains outdated informations that do not apply for Milestone 4, see [here](http://news.dartlang.org/2013/04/goodbye-invocationmirror-hello.html?utm_source=feedly) for the changes.

**Something like this:**

```
typedef dynamic FunctionWithArguments(List<dynamic> positionalArguments, Map<Symbol, dynamic> namedArguments);

class MyFunction
{
  final FunctionWithArguments function;

  MyFunction(this.function);

  dynamic noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    if(invocation.isMethod && invocation.memberName == const Symbol('call')) {
      return function(invocation.positionalArguments, invocation.namedArguments);
    }

    return;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
class AClass {
  final aMethod = new MyFunction((p, n) {
    for(var a in p) {
      print(a);
    }
  });
}


var b = new AClass();

b.aMethod(12, 324, 324);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dart does indirectly support var-args as long as you as you aren't too much into syntactic brevity.

```
void testFunction([List<dynamic> args=[]])
{
  for(dynamic arg:args)
  {
    // Handle each arg...
  }
}

testFunction([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
testFunction();
testFunction([0, 1, 2]);
```

**Note:** You can do the same thing with named parameters, but you'll have to handle things internally, just in case if the user (of that function; which could be you) decides to not pass any value to that named parameter.

Comment: It's true that Dart's lightweight list literal syntax makes the lack of varargs less painful that it would otherwise be, but think it's a bit of a stretch to claim support here - kinda the entire point of varargs is syntactic sugar to support variable number of arguments _without_ having to wrap it in a collection.