# How are arguments moved in bulk from one function to another, in Dart?

Tags: dart, apply

In Javascript, one can use `apply` to move arguments in bulk from one function to another? How is this done in Dart?

To use a mismatch of Dart and Javascript:

```
Object proxy(<any number and type of arguments>) {
    if(feelGood) 
        return goodFunc.apply(arguments);
    else 
        return badFunc.apply(arguments);
}
```

In Dart, how does one

- specify any number and type of arguments?
- apply the arguments from one function to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Function.apply](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Function.html#apply) :

```dart
main() {
  final l = [];
  Function.apply(l.add, ['v1']);
  print(l);  // display "[v1]"
}
```

Dart does not support varargs on method but you can simulate them with `noSuchMethod` (see [Creating function with variable number of arguments or parameters in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731631/creating-function-with-variable-number-of-arguments-or-parameters-in-dart))

Comment: good going - but does seem an awfully round about solution to a pretty simple problem.  I vote for Dart having "..." in the arguments and let the programmer deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a function that takes any number of arguments in Dart. For that, you have to fall back on noSuchMethod. To call a function with a dynamic list of arguments, you can use Function.apply.

Example:

```dart
class _MyProxy implements Function {
  const _MyProxy();
  noSuchMethod(InvocationMirror m) {
    if (m.memberName != #call) return super.noSuchMethod(m);
    return Function.apply(feelGood ? goodFunc : badFunc, m.positionalArguments, m.namedArguments);
  }
}
const Function proxy = const _MyProxy();
```

This class captures invalid calls using noSuchMethod. It acts as a function by intercepting the "call" method. It then works as your proxy method intends by forwarding the arguments to either goodFunc or badFunc using Function.apply.

You can then write:

```
proxy(<any number and type of argument>);
```

and have it call either goodFunc or badFunc with those exact arguments.