# Get a collection of arguments passed to a Dart function/constructor call

Tags: dart

I'm essentially looking for the [JavaScript `arguments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633125/is-it-possible-to-get-all-arguments-of-a-function-as-single-object-inside-that-f) functionality but in Dart.

Is this possible in Dart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to play with `noSuchMethod` to do that (see [Creating function with variable number of arguments or parameters in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13731631/634863))

Either at the class level:

```dart
class A {
  noSuchMethod(Invocation i) {
    if (i.isMethod && i.memberName == #myMethod){
      print(i.positionalArguments);
    }
  }
}

main() {
  var a = new A();
  a.myMethod(1, 2, 3);  // no completion and a warning
}
```

Or at field level :

```dart
typedef dynamic OnCall(List l);

class VarargsFunction extends Function {
  OnCall _onCall;

  VarargsFunction(this._onCall);

  call() => _onCall([]);

  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    final arguments = invocation.positionalArguments;
    return _onCall(arguments);
  }
}

class A {
  final myMethod = new VarargsFunction((arguments) => print(arguments));
}

main() {
  var a = new A();
  a.myMethod(1, 2, 3);
}
```

The second option allows to have code completion for `myMethod` and avoid a warning.

Comment: Would either of these approaches work for a constructor?

Comment: No, but you can use a static method what finally return an instance.